# Running out of memory when processing 4 million records

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, .net-3.5, sqldatareader

I have the following code which attempts to process 4,000,000 database records:

```
private void intenseProcess4()
{
    using (connection1 = new SqlConnection("connection string goes here"))
    {
        using (command1 = new SqlCommand(@"stored procedure name goes here", connection1))
        {
            command1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            try
            {
                connection1.Open();

                using (reader1 = command1.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader1.Read())
                    {
                        int PrjNameIndex1 = reader1.GetOrdinal("full_path");
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(reader1.GetString(PrjNameIndex1)));
                    }

                    if (reader1.NextResult())
                    {
                        while (reader1.Read())
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Copy(reader1.GetString(SourceIndex), reader1.GetString(DestinationIndex), true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(@"h:\X\log\error.log"), ex + " SqlException caught." + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once started, it works fine for about an hour, but then it gives the following error message:

```
Problem signature:
    Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
    Problem Signature 01:   devenv.exe
    Problem Signature 02:   12.0.21005.1
    Problem Signature 03:   524fcb34
    Problem Signature 04:   mscorlib
    Problem Signature 05:   4.0.30319.34209
    Problem Signature 06:   534894cc
Problem Signature 07:   226e
Problem Signature 08:   6
Problem Signature 09:   System.OutOfMemoryException
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.49
Locale ID:  2057
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

In that time, it only gets through around 35 thousand records

Comment: Note that the lines `String DestinationString =` and `String SourceString = ` are useless. Still this shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Looks like you're running this from inside VS. Make sure you're using a Release build and preferably outside VS.

Comment: @xanatos, Sorry, was using those in console.log to see what's going on. Removed that line to simply the question, but I guess it just added to the confusion...

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I'll try that now.  If it gives an error again, I guess I will be back in about an hour, as that's roughly how long it takes to get the error above.

Comment: I totally agree with Holterman analysis. If it still doesn't work (but it would be very strange, because you aren't allocating much GC memory), you could try to do a `GC.Collect()` every 1000 files. Before the `while`: `int num = 0;` inside the `while`: `if (++num % 1000 == 0) { GC.Collect(); }`

Comment: @oshirowanen - How big are your files? The error could come from LOH fragmentation. For a real answer you'd need to attach a profiler. For a start, see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273

Comment: @HenkHolterman: The files are just copied, not read into managed memory.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, in total, the files are about 1TB.  Each individual file in size varies.  They seem to average about 0.25MB.

Comment: @Guffa - probably, I'd have to dive into the sources for File.Copy. It was just my hunch that it might allocate managed buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a terminal command instead of the GUI to create an archive.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When you specify SequentialAccess, you are required to read from the columns in the order they are returned, although you are not required to read each column. Once you have read past a location in the returned stream of data, data at or before that location can no longer be read from the DataReader.

But the wisdom of attempting to process *in one pass* 4M record is questionable. I'm pretty sure you will *never* succeed in copying 4M files *and* keep a result set open. You are doomed to keep retrying over and over again. Consider instead using batches, retrieve a small set of files to process, copy, write down progress, then get another batch. In case of crash, resume from the last progress.

You should also consider doing several copies in parallel (using async IO, not threads!).

Comment: I'm not so sure about that last point, File.Copy can easily saturate a single drive.

Comment: And on second thought not so sure about the first one either. The file-contents are not in the Db, just the filenames.

Comment: The reader streams data. There should not be more memory use than about 1 row at a time. I don't see why arbitrarily many records would be a problem per se.